# Table Image Add Vertical Lines Between

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm trying to add a vertical line on the image below. The image is a region of interest. I used the below code to add both vertical and horizontal lines but it's not working. The colution below attempts to add vertical and horintal lines but not working. The attached image is a region of interest that has been threshold.

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('table4b.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold on white
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# average gray image to one row
row = cv2.resize(thresh, (ww, 1), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

# threshold on white
thresh1 = cv2.threshold(row, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply small amount of morphology to merge period with column of text
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (5,1))
thresh1 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# get contours
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
result = img.copy()
result1 = img.copy()
for cntr in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    xcenter = x + w // 2
    cv2.line(result1, (xcenter,0), (xcenter, hh-1), (0, 0, 0), 1)
    cv2.line(result, (xcenter,0), (xcenter, hh-1), (0, 0, 0), 1)

# average gray image to one column
column = cv2.resize(thresh, (1, hh), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

# threshold on white
thresh2 = cv2.threshold(column, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
# get contours

contours = cv2.findContours(thresh2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
result2 = img.copy()
for cntr in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    ycenter = y + h // 2
    cv2.line(result2, (0, ycenter), (ww-1, ycenter), (0, 0, 0), 1)
    cv2.line(result, (0, ycenter), (ww-1, ycenter), (0, 0, 0), 1)
```

expected Results:
[image]